# Laravel - Notification failed to save to database but generated error

Tags: laravel, notifications

I've been on this issue for some days now. Using Laravel-5.8, I created this notifications table:

```
CREATE TABLE `notifications` (
  `id` char(36) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `sent_to` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `send_by` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `subject` varchar(75) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `notification_type` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'goal setting, goal approval, goal rejecttion',
  `data` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `is_read` tinyint(4) DEFAULT 0,
  `read_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4
```

I want to send notifications to users and save it into database as well.

NotificationController

```
public function notify_users(){

  $userCompany = Auth::user()->company_id;
  $userEmployee = Auth::user()->employee_id;    
  $userId = Auth::user()->id;
  $userEmail = Auth::user()->email;
  $userCode = Auth::user()->employee_code;
  $userFirstName = Auth::user()->first_name;
  $userLastName = Auth::user()->last_name;   

  $identities = DB::table('appraisal_identity')->select('id')->where('company_id', $userCompany)->where('is_current', 1)->first();
  $reviewperiods = DB::table('appraisal_identity')->select('appraisal_name')->where('company_id', $userCompany)->where('is_current', 1)->first();
$reviewperiod = $reviewperiods->appraisal_name; 

$linemanager = DB::table('hr_employees')->where('id', $userEmployee)->first();
$linemanageremails = DB::table('hr_employees')->select('email')->where('line_manager_id', $linemanager->line_manager_id)->first();
$linemanageremail = $linemanageremails->email;
$linemanagerfirstnames = DB::table('hr_employees')->select('first_name')->where('line_manager_id', $linemanager->line_manager_id)->first();
$linemanagerfirstname = $linemanagerfirstnames->first_name;
$linemanagerlastnames = DB::table('hr_employees')->select('last_name')->where('line_manager_id', $linemanager->line_manager_id)->first();
$linemanagerlastname = $linemanagerlastnames->last_name;
$linemanagerids = DB::table('hr_employees')->select('id')->where('line_manager_id', $linemanager->line_manager_id)->first();
$linemanagerid = $linemanagerids->id;

$unapproved_count = AppraisalGoal::where('employee_id', $userEmployee)->where('appraisal_identity_id', $identities->id)->where('is_approved',0)->count();

if ($unapproved_count > 3){
$unapproved_post = AppraisalGoal::where('employee_id', $userEmployee)->where('appraisal_identity_id', $identities->id)->where('is_approved',0)
        ->update([
            'is_approved' => 1              
            ]);

$unapproved_post = AppraisalGoal::where('employee_id', $userEmployee)->where('appraisal_identity_id', $identities->id)->where('is_approved',1)->first();


$details = [
    'sent_to' => $linemanagerid,
    'sent_by' => $userId,
    'subject' => 'Approved by: ' .$userCode .'for '.$reviewperiod,
    'greeting' => 'Hello, '.$linemanagerfirstname . ' '. $linemanagerlastname . '!',
    'body' =>  'The employee with the code: ' . $userCode . 'and Fullname: ' .$userFirstName. ' ' .$userLastName .' ' .'has approved his/her goals for the Review Period: ' .$reviewperiod . ' '. 'for your approval.',
    'line1' => 'The employee with the code: ' . $userCode . 'and Fullname: ' .$userFirstName. ' ' .$userLastName,
    'line2' => 'has approved his/her goals for the Review Period: ' .$reviewperiod,
    'line3' => 'for your approval.',
    'thanks' => 'Thank you!',            
    'user_fullname' => $userFirstName. ' ' . $userLastName,
    'user_code' => $userCode,
    'user_email' => $userEmail,
    'user_id' => $userId,
    'line_manager_full_name' => $linemanagerfirstname. ' ' . $linemanagerlastname,
    'review_periond' => $reviewperiod,
    'line_manager_email' => $linemanageremail,
    'line_manager_id' => $linemanagerid,
    'notification_type' => 'goal setting',

];

    Notification::route('mail', $details['line_manager_email'])
            ->notify(new \App\Notifications\Appraisal\AppraisalGoalApprove($details));


    Session::flash('success', 'Approved successfully');
    return redirect()->back();
}else{
    Session::flash('info', 'Approval Failed!');
    return redirect()->back();
 } 
}
```

As I stated earlier. I want to send email notification and also save into the database.

Notifications

```
class AppraisalGoalApprove extends Notification implements ShouldQueue
{
  use Queueable;
  private $details;

 public function __construct($details)
 {
     $this->details = $details;
 }

public function via($notifiable)
{
    return ['mail','database'];
}

public function toMail($notifiable)
{
   return (new MailMessage)
            ->subject($this->details['subject'])
            ->greeting($this->details['greeting'])
            ->line($this->details['line1'])
            ->line($this->details['line2'])
            ->line($this->details['line3'])
            ->line($this->details['thanks']);
}


public function toDatabase($notifiable)
{ 
   return [
    'subject' => $this->details['subject'],
    'sent_to' => $this->details['sent_to'],
    'sent_by' => $this->details['sent_by'],
    'notification_type' => $this->details['notification_type'],
    'data' => $this->details['body']
  ];
}   

public function toArray($notifiable)
{
    return [
     //
    ];
 }
}
```

When I submitted the form, The notification was sent to the user, but it was not saved into the database. The I got this error:

Call to a member function create() on null

This is the line of code that is underlined:

```
class DatabaseChannel
{
  public function send($notifiable, Notification $notification)
  {
    return $notifiable->routeNotificationFor('database', $notification)->create(
        $this->buildPayload($notifiable, $notification)
    );
  }
}
```

How do I get this error resolved?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Do you do the follwoing artisan command ?

```
php artisan notifications:table

php artisan migrate
```

Comment: Yes, I did. But I changed some fields in the table as shown in the code. As I state, it sends notification, but it doesn't save